# Why is my text ending up behind my image?

Tags: java, awt

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {

    g.drawImage(backGround, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
    //Draw the duck, Starting coordinates are 15,15.  DuckHeight/Width =60 (Defined Above)
    g.drawImage(duck1, 15, 15, DuckHeight, DuckWidth, this);
    //Draw the images to the screen in the order from background to foreground
    bufferGraphics.drawImage(duck1, xduck, yduck, this);

    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 18));
    g.drawString("Score: " + ScoreCounter, 100, 100);

}
```

I commented out the lines of code that would draw the images, and the string successfully appeared. Why is my string being drawn behind my images?

Comment: Why are you using paint() instead of paintComponent()?

Comment: @Reimeus, Well, it hides behind the background image, and the background image covers the whole screen.

Comment: @Dodd10x Im using paint() because it was explained in my classes handout. What is the benifit of using paintComponent() instead?

Comment: PaintComponent is the last method in the paint chain, which you've broken, which is going to cause more issues. What is bufferGraphics?

Comment: If you are using Swing, then your instructor is wrong.  You should not be using paint().  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/